# How to resize the drawing of the canvas in HTML5?

Tags: html, canvas, resize

I would like to resize the canvas to  a smaller dimension than what it is. Here is my code:

```
             var modelPane = document.getElementById('model_pane');


        //create canvasclass="modelview"
        var canvas_ = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas_.setAttribute('width', 1160);
        canvas_.setAttribute('height', 500);
        canvas_.setAttribute('id', 'canvas');
        canvas_.setAttribute('class', 'modelview');
        var ctx_ = canvas_.getContext('2d');

        //draw
        for (i=0;i<nodes.length;i++)
                            {
            ctx_.strokeRect(nodes[i].x,  nodes[i].y, nodes[i].width, nodes[i].height);


    }

        //scale
        ctx_.scale(0.3,0.3);
    modelPane.appendChild(canvas_);
```

Yet this doesn't work. Anyone know why? The canvas doesn't resize to the new dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call scale first:

```
var ctx_ = canvas_.getContext('2d');
ctx_.scale(0.3,0.3);
//draw
for (i=0;i<nodes.length;i++)
    ctx_.strokeRect(nodes[i].x,  nodes[i].y, nodes[i].width, nodes[i].height);
}
```

Think about it, like you need to scale you canvas down. Then draw on the smaller canvas.
[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/s2vyQ/)

Comment: Thanks @IAbstractDownvoteFactory .Now I have a small problem. That works, however, the canvas element size stays the same. I would like the canvas element to be the same size as the scale down version. I'm basically trying to implement (thumbnail) canvases and when the user clicks on the thumbnail it leads to the real sized canvas. Any idea?

Comment: Actually, I just set the initial canvas element size to the thumbnail size and it worked! Might have to play around with it a little bit though! Thanks for the help!